# Shell Script won't kill PID when run by shairport-sync

Tags: raspbian, linux, bash, shairplay

I am currently running shairport-sync on a raspberry pi zero running raspbian lite. Everything works well, but I am choosing to use a soundcard for auxillary input as well.

I currently have these scripts to run at the beginning before a device connects to shairport and after shairport ends playback.

the script run when a device connects is as follows:`shairportstart.sh`

```
!/bin/bash
/bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep are | /bin/grep -v /bin/grep | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'| /usr/bin/xargs /usr/bin/sudo /bin/kill
sleep 5s
if [ $(date +%H) -ge "18" -o $(date +%H) -le "7" ]; then
    amixer set Speaker 100%
else
    amixer -c 1 set Speaker 100%
fi
/home/pi/shScripts/shairportfade.sh&

exit 0
```

then the script that is being run after shairport ends is as follows:`shairportend.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
amixer set Speaker 70%
arecord -D plughw:1 -f dat | aplay -D plughw:1 -f dat&
exit 0
```

I have tried changing the shebang from #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash but neither of them work to kill the PID, but they still change the amixer level.

from the terminal when I run

```
/bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep are | /bin/grep -v /bin/grep | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'| /usr/bin/xargs /usr/bin/sudo /bin/kill
```

the PID signal is terminated and shairport is able to begin playing the music from the device connected to it. Even when I run the script from the terminal it terminates properly, but it does not do so otherwise.

Is there something I am missing or not doing properly? Any help is appreciated.

I have tried searching multiple topics related to killing the PID and none of them work. I have tried kill -9, kill all, but none seem to work.

I have raised an issue on shairport-sync github page, but I was told it was a possible difference between runtime environments, I have tried searching on that subject as well but came up with nothing.

Comment: I take it the process not die with `sudo kill [pid]`?

Comment: It does within the terminal, but does not when run in a script

Comment: Sorry, about above premature question. Have you enabled debugging in your bash script? `#!/bin/bash -x -v` to help you find where it's getting caught up? Permissions may be another issue you could be running into.

Comment: No worries, I didn't even think of using the shebang as a way of debugging I will try that possibly tomorrow to see what is happening. I don't know that will help as shairport runs the script behind the scenes. Does your method log the output somewhere that I can go to check later. I have also posted my answer as what fixed the issue. I believe it is a permissions issue but I believe the script doesn't have enough permission to kill the given PIDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved the issue. When `shairport-sync` is enabled with `systemctl` and enabled as suggested in the readme.md, a script is unable to kill the process due to the need for `sudo`. Since `systemd` is run early in the boot process, it loads `shairport-sync` before `/etc/sudoers` is loaded. Then since `systemd` runs in a consistent environment it runs the process without any `sudo` rules. That being said, each time `sudo` is needed it will require a password, which is the error that is occuring and not allowing for the `kill` command to execute.

There are a few work arounds to solve this issue.

The first solution is running `sudo systemctl disable shairport-sync`. Then add `/home/pi/shairport-sync/shairport-sync&` to the end of your `/etc/rc.local` file.

The next solution is to change sudo permissions via `sudo visudo`. From there you can add `shairport-sync ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` anywhere in the file, I chose to add it to the end of the file.

The last solution and possibly the simplest, is change your kill line from

`/bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep are | /bin/grep -v /bin/grep | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'| /usr/bin/xargs /usr/bin/sudo /bin/kill`

to

```
/usr/bin/echo "yourpasswordhere" | /usr/bin/sudo /bin/pkill arecord
```

EDIT:

While this is not completely related, this installation automatically sets up shairport-sync and allows for this line input with minor configuration changes:
https://github.com/BaReinhard/Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install-Car-Install